# CSRF: Signed Double Submit Cookie & 'Referer' validation vs MITM and vulnerable subdomains

Tags: man-in-the-middle, csrf, hmac, referer

I have been researching various techniques for preventing CSRF attacks, such as SOP, `SameSite`, `Secure`, `Referer` validation, and CSRF Tokens, and their potential bypasses. During my research, I discovered the following vulnerabilities:

1. A website's subdomain or sibling domain is vulnerable to XSS or HTML Injection. For instance:

   - Subdomain: `a.com` and `vulnerable.a.com`
   - Sibling: `a.a.com` and `vulnerable.a.com`
2. A subdomain takeover (SDTO) attack
3. A Man-in-the-middle (MITM) attack

However, I'm unsure if correctly implemented *Signed Double Submit Cookie* and **`Referer` validation** are vulnerable to those?

---

#### What I mean by correctly implemented:

- With **Signed Double Submit** is meant a session-bound and signed (HMAC) CSRF token, stored in a non-`HttpOnly` cookie with the `Secure` flag.
- With **`Referer` validation** is meant a **Strict** (block requests that have no `Referer` header) and **Strong** ([handles subdomain and URL queries](https://portswigger.net/web-security/csrf/bypassing-referer-based-defenses)) `Referer` validation.

---

#### Questions:

1. **Is *Signed Double Submit Cookie* & *Strict & Strong `Referer` validation* vulnerable to MITM?**

   According to [this SO answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/61039/232124):

   > ... If an application is hosted at `https://secure.example.com`, even if the cookies are set with the secure flag, a man in the middle can force connections to `http://secure.example.com` and set (overwrite) any arbitrary cookies (even though the secure flag prevents the attacker from reading those cookies)...

   If I read this correctly, this would mean that a MITM can initiate requests from `http://b.com` to `http://a.com`, but make the request look like it came from `http://a.com`. If that is true, then:

   - *Signed Double Submit Cookie* is vulnerable. The attacker doesn't even need to overwrite the CSRF cookie, since the original one is passed along automatically
   - *Strict & Strong `Referer` validation* is vulnerable. The request, even if made from `b.com` has the value `a.com` as the `Referer` value.
2. **Is *Signed Double Submit Cookie* vulnerable to a vulnerable subdomain?**
   If an attacker gains access to `vulnerable.a.com`, they can read and write any cookie.

   Is it true that only [cookie prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#attributes) prevent such an attack, or am I missing something where the *Signed Double Submit Cookie* pattern would prevent this?
3. **Is  *Strict & Strong `Referer` validation* vulnerable to vulnerable subdomain?**
   Let's look over some facts:

   - The `Referer` header is a [forbidden header name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy) meaning it cannot be changed programmatically.
   - The session cookie or JWT are commonly protected with the `HttpOnly` flag, preventing the attacker from reading or writing to it, even on subdomains.

   With that in mind, does this mean that *Strict & Strong `Referer` validation* is not vulnerable to vulnerable subdomains?
4. **Is OWASP's recommendation false?**
   The *Signed Double Submit Cookie* pattern is [categorized as a mitigation technique](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#double-submit-cookie).
   The *Strict & Strong `Referer` validation* pattern is only [categorized as a Defence in Depth (DiD) technique](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#checking-the-referer-header).

   Depending on the above questions, it may seem that only a combination of a *Signed Double Submit Cookie* and *Strict & Strong `Referer` validation* is a true mitigation technique, while alone both are DiD's?

Comment: The OWASP tag doesn't apply to this question, and you have no need for special formatting of your question.

Comment: @schroeder I would usually agree with the special formatting, but your changes disorganize the indentation, making it more difficult to read what belongs together. I was just using vanilla Markdown to make it more segmented and thereby more readable. Have you looked at the text after bullet point 1 & 2?

Comment: If you are needing that much formatting and all that supporting material, that might be a sign that you are trying to cram too many independent questions into a single post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to 1):

I think you misunderstand the linked paper. What the paragraph says is that *naive* double-submit cookies can be defeated through a man-in-the-middle attack:

- Scenario 1: The legitimate application is reachable over HTTPS, and the double-submit cookie has the `Secure` flag set. However, if the client makes a connection over HTTP, then a man-in-the-middle can overwrite the double-submit cookie (not read the existing one) and thereby defeat the protection.
- Scenario 2: The application is reachable over HTTPS, the double-submit cookie has the `Secure` flag set, and the server enforces HTTPS connections for the primary domain (but not subdomains) through HSTS. If the client makes an HTTP connection to a subdomain, then a man-in-the-middle can still overwrite the double-submit cookie (not read it) through this subdomain.

A double submit cookie with a MAC (or “signed cookie” as you call it) and the `Secure` flag set does not have this issue. Since the attacker can neither read the current `Secure` cookie nor calculate the MAC for their own token, they cannot do a classical CSRF attack. However, as soon as plaintext HTTP is used, there are of course all kinds of other issues which may make CSRF completely unnecessary. For example, when a client makes an HTTP request to the target website, the attacker could simply show the log-in form in the response and wait for the client to enter their credentials.

As to 2):

An attacker who controls a subdomain can *set* cookies for all higher-order domains (except for public suffixes) and make them be sent to all corresponding subdomains, but they cannot *read* arbitrary cookies. This is why double-submit cookies with a MAC are useful. If the legitimate application at `a.com` stores an anti-CSRF token with a MAC inside a cookie that has no domain set, then this cookie will not be sent to subdomains. The subdomains can try to set their own anti-CSRF token, but since they're not able to create a valid MAC, the token will be rejected by the server.

As to 3):

If the server checks the exact domain of the referrer, then this validation is not vulnerable to subdomain-based attack. However, there are valid reasons for users to disable the referrer (e. g. to enhance privacy), so you cannot assume it's present.

As to 4):

No, the OWASP recommendations are not false. A double-submit cookies with a MAC and the right properties (empty domain, or cookie prefix) is a good solution. Referrer checks are unreliable, since there may not be a referrer at all. At best, this would be a second line of defense in case the referrer is set.

Comment: As to 1): Thanks, you cleared up some things there. I definitely misread that part because I couldn't find anything on the web that mentions similar.

Comment: As to 2): I see now. However, it seems then that an attacker does not have to read or set a CSRF Token. They can send any CSRF attacks from the vulnerable subdomain, even with `SameSite` in place. The original session and CSRF cookie are passed during the request. Only [cookie prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#attributes) would fix this issue?

Comment: As to 3): I strongly agree. On the other hand, I have seen it heavily implemented in the wild (Strict `Referer` validation). Django's CSRF Middleware uses a combination of session-independent CSRF tokens + `Origin` validation + `Referer` validation. It also seemed that when Brave placed `noreferrer` on all pages, it [broke many websites](https://brave.com/privacy-updates/5-grab-bag/#2referrer-policy-changes).

Comment: As to 4): Lovely, thanks for your answer!

Comment: To 2): To defeat cookie-based CSRF protection (even the naive variant), an attacker has to know the token, so that they can include it in the request parameters. If they simply create a form and make the victim's browser submit it, yes, the anti-CSRF cookie will be automatically included in the request, but there's no matching parameter. It's only half of the double submission. So the attacker either has to read the existing token or set their own (unless this is prevented with a MAC).

Comment: [@Ja1024](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/291964/ja1024) - this is embarrassing. Of course! I've been working too much today. That's the whole point of the Double Submit Cookie pattern! Thanks so much for your time!